# How to properly redirect from old url to new with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok I recently finished cleaning up my urls.
But i still have pages in google indexed under the old urls.
In .htaccess i was trying something like:

```
    RedirectMatch permanent ^profile2.php?id=([^/]+) /profile/$1
```

but it doesn't seem to be working..help anyone? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `/profile/` is your new URL or old style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a 301 permanent redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^profile2.php?id=([^/]+) /profile/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: @DavidIvanov: On the contrary it's good for SEO, a 301 redirect is the correct way to tell search engines that a document's location has permanently changed. I'm not sure why that doesn't work, there's nothing wrong with the rule I've just tried it and it forwards a request for `profile2.php?id=test` to `/profile/test`. Can you provide an example for which it isn't working?